# Using indirect within an array

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to use an array formula which has an indirect within it.  The formula returns #VALUE however if I solve the 'indirect' portion of the array using F9 then solve the rest of the array, it works.  Any ideas?

The following is the formula, hopefully this is helpful without the raw data:

```
=SUM((dat = x)*(dat)*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS((MATCH(dat)),MATCH(dat))))
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more background? `INDIRECT(ADDRESS((MATCH(dat)),MATCH(dat)))` seems really weird - what do you want to achieve with that? Maybe you can replace `INDIRECT` with an `INDEX` function. or `SUM` as array with a normal `SUMPRODUCT`  - but to judge/test one needs to understand a bit more.

Comment: I don't understand that MATCH(dat) at all...MATCH requires at least 2 parameters

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take the results of the previous two arguments in my array and multiply them by a scaling factor.  There are many different scaling factors, all of which are within a table, I was trying to reference this table with the last jumble (Indirect onward).